# Como excluir uma linha que contenha letras em um dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, ciência-de-dados

Quero excluir linhas que contenham letras nesse ***dataframe***

```
dic = {'Código':dataframe['Cod'], 'Dimensões': list_no_x}

new_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(dic)

print(new_dataframe)
```

A saída fica assim:

```
   Código  Dimensões
0    1623   10 15 7 
1    5124   15 7 8 
2    4785   20 15 8
3    5251   50 70 22 
4    1578   c10 l20
5    9684   50 10 2 
6    5187   75 20 10
```

Eu quero remover todas as linhas que ***contenham letras ou tenham menos que 3 dimensões*** na coluna de dimensões.

Comment: O que tentou fazer para solucionar e foi o problema encontrado?

Answer (score 0):

Para **verificar se existência de letras** você pode utilizar o [`pandas.Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html#pandas.Series.str.contains) passando como parâmetro para a busca um RegExp como `r'[a-zA-Z]'` para criar uma tabela verdade onde letras sejam encontradas.

E para **verificar a quantidade de dimensões** você pode contar a ocorrência de espaços [`pandas.Series.str.count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.count.html#pandas-series-str-count)

Ex.:

```py
import pandas as pd

dados = { 
    "Código": [1623,5124,4785,5251,1578,9684,5187, 111, 222, 333, 444, 555 ],
    "Dimensões":["10 15 7", "15 7 8", "20 15 8", 
                "50 70 22", "c10 l20", "50 10 2",
                "75 20 10", "10 cl20", "1c0 l20", "111 212", "111 22 33", "11 22 33 44"],
}

# Criar o DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame( dados )

# Criar uma TABELA VERDADE para selecionar 
# as linhas que contem letras na coluna 'Dimensões'
com_letras = df['Dimensões'].str.contains(r'[A-Za-z]')

print( "# tabela verdade de linhas que contem letras na coluna 'Dimensões':" )
print( com_letras )
print( "\n")


print( "# df de linhas COM letras na coluna 'Dimensões':")
print( df[ com_letras ] )
print( "\n")


# Criar uma TABELA VERDADE para selecionar
# as linhas não tem 2 espaços na coluna 'Dimensões':
dif_2espacos = df['Dimensões'].str.count(' ') != 2

print( "# tabela verdade de linhas não tem 2 espaços na coluna 'Dimensões':")
print(dif_2espacos)
print( "\n")


print( "# df de linhas não tem 2 espaços na coluna 'Dimensões':")
print(df[ dif_2espacos ])
print( "\n")


# Agora você pode utilizar bitwise `~` (NOT)
# para negar uma TABELA VERDADE e dessa forma
# transformar quem é TRUE em FALSE e vice-versa
# e depois bitwise `&` (AND) onde ambas tabelas 
# sejam verdadeiras, ou seja:
# sem_letras = ~com_letras
# tem_2espacos = ~dif_2espacos
# sem_letras_E_tem_2espacos = sem_letras & tem_2espacos
# df = df[ sem_letras_E_tem_2espacos ].copy()
df = df[ ~tem_letras & ~dif_2espacos ].copy()

print("# df de linhas ( SEM letras AND COM 2 espacos ) na coluna 'Dimensões' :")
print(df)
```

<sup>[Exemplo Online - ideone](https://ideone.com/QqYZL9)</sup>

> **TL;DR;**
>
> ```
> df[ ~df['Dimensões'].str.contains(r'[A-Za-z]') &\
>      (df['Dimensões'].str.count(' ') == 2) ]
> ```
>
> <sup>[Exemplo Online - ideone](https://ideone.com/yIyUNy)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Você pode encontrar as linhas que tem apenas números tirando os espaços e testando se é numérico

```
df=df[ df["Dimensões"].apply( lambda x: x.replace(" ", "").isnumeric() ) ]
```